# Dynamic Object vs Non dynamic object in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, c++11, dynamic

When do you want to use a dynamically allocated object such as, https://leetcode.com/problems/design-twitter/,

- Your Twitter object will be instantiated and called as such:
- Twitter* obj = new Twitter();
- obj->postTweet(userId,tweetId);
- vector param_2 = obj->getNewsFeed(userId);
- obj->follow(followerId,followeeId);
- obj->unfollow(followerId,followeeId);

[ie pointer to a new object]

or a (static?) object such as, https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-nested-list-iterator/:

- Your NestedIterator object will be instantiated and called as such:
- NestedIterator i(nestedList);
- while (i.hasNext()) cout << i.next();

[ie standard object initialization]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please don't use such sites as a learning resource, because they're not. Get [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read if you want to learn C++. It should hlep you understand when and where to use "dynamic objects". I also recommend taking a few classes, and learn common algorithms and data structure, discrete math, and other programming languages, if you want to become more than a simple code moneky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually dynamically allocate objects if you do not know upfront how many of those you will need or if objects instances need to be shared between users.
As a side note, never use `new` use the `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead.